# In a city of skyscrapers, how would the height affect the individuals living there?

Tags: science-based, magic, science-fiction, atmosphere

I'm writing a sci-fi/fantasy story that partially takes place in a supercity (Pop 15 Bil) made of skyscrapers. The inhabitants thereof are immortal, and so don't have to be concerned about atmospheric things like breathing at such insane heights and the like, but my question centers around the following:

How much louder would people have to speak at the top floors to talk over the wind?

Approximately how complex would the transportation of industrial materials be?

Could there be walkways between buildings without barriers to protect from wind?

What would the energy consumption be like, and what solutions would/could there be to keep up with it?

Any other things you think I should consider?

Comment: "*How much louder would people have to speak at the top floors to talk over the wind?*" Insulated.  The walls and windows would be insulated, both from temperature and from noise.

Comment: Also, why are the inhabitants always immortal, and what does immortality have to do with whether or not "atmospheric things like breathing at such insane heights" would make you **miserable but not dead**?

Comment: The question, as written, is not really about worldbuilding: it is opinion based and focuses more on emotion & psychology. Every individual is her own person. Each one will be affected in a unique and distinct way based on her mental & cognitive wiring, her personality, her upbringing and early set of unique experiences. If you can ask a question and, after half a minute's reflection, determine that the answer is something like "obviously, the effects will be different for different individuals", then you probably have not crafted a well thought out question! You also ask **SEVEN** questions!!

Comment: This might have been an interesting question if not for the whole "immortal and perfect health" thing.

It'd be interesting to see how someone living at an extreme height in a pressurized environment would physiologically change over time.

Comment: So basically you are asking a question about : 1-noise at high altitude: indoor or outdoor? What's the altitude? 2- transportation of what to where for what purpose? Construction? industries? 3- barriers: at what altitude? 4-energy consumption: assuming it is in the far future, this is not easy to answer and it's also a completely different topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I am not understanding the problem with skyscrapers.  Take a city of skyscrapers and scale it up.

Here is Hong Kong, a city of skyscrapers.

[image: hong kong at night]
http://www.skyscrapercenter.com/city/hong-kong

http://www.newgeography.com/content/002808-world-urban-areas-population-and-density-a-2012-update

> Among the urban areas with more than 2.5 million population, the
>   second-most dense is Mumbai, at 80,100 per square mile or 30,900 per
>   square kilometer. The most dense high income world urban area is Hong
>   Kong, at 67,000 persons per square mile or 25,900 per square
>   kilometer.

So 15,000,000,000 / 25900 = 579150 square km or a Hong Kong the size of the island of Madagascar.

I imagine the system for supplies and construction could be much like that of Hong Kong, scaled up.

You would not hear the wind too much on the upper floors because there would be windows to keep it out.

You would probably not have gangplanks connecting these buildings but you could have enclosed skyways or bridges. People like those better for some reason.  High bridges are not something you see too often and I am not sure why.  Maybe because skyscrapers sway slightly and the movement is greater the higher you go.  But the Petronas towers have a bridge that is high up, and your skyscrapers could too.

[image: petronas towers with bridge]
https://andoyoanny.wordpress.com/category/skyscrapers/